# Assigning deciles using bash

Tags: bash

I'm learning bash, and here's a short script to assign deciles to the second column of file $1.

The complicating bit is the use of awk within the script, leading to `ambiguous redirects` when I run the script.

I would have gotten this done in SAS by now, but like the idea of two lines of code doing the job.

How can I communicate the total number of rows (${N}) to awk within the script? Thanks.

```
  N=$(wc -l < $1)
  cat $1 | sort -t' ' -k2gr,2 | awk '{$3=int((((NR-1)*10.0)/"${N}")+1);print $0}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an `awk` variable from the command line using `-v`.

```
N=$(wc -l < "$1" | tr -d ' ')
sort -t' ' -k2gr,2 "$1" | awk -v n=$N '{$3=int((((NR-1)*10.0)/n)+1);print $0}'
```

I added `tr -d` to get rid of the leading spaces that `wc -l` puts in its result.